# Which C# general structure is recommended to convert a PHP Array to C#?

Tags: c#, php, arrays

We are consuming a PHP Web Service. 
We have generated the WSDL using Add Web Service Reference in Visual Studio.

The getOurRequest Service method expects a "object" type of input parameter.

The PHP Documentation for this method has the following array declared in PHP.

```
$getOurRequest =>array( 
    `aaaa`=> ‘1111’,
    `bbbb`=> ‘2222’,
    `ccccArray`=> array(
            ‘cccc3333’
                ,‘cccc4444‘
),
    `ddddArray`=>array(
            'dddd5555'
            ,'dddd6666'
            )
);
```

How do we convert it into C# for use to call the PHP Web Service ?

Any ideas to help with the solution or general serializable structure preferred to pass to the Web Service would be appreciated.

@quetzalcoatl Thank you for the var c# declaration sample. It was helpful but it does not serialize over the service call.

Comment: Oftentimes it's beneficial for you to tell us what you're really trying to do, rather than how you want to do it.  This seems rather dubious, and might not be the approach you really want to take.  (Having an associative array in which they keys are of different types.)

Comment: Did you generate a WSDL?

Comment: Would it be possible for this to be an array of arrays of strings, rather than an array of something that is either a string or an array?  Some of the inner arrays could be of size 1.  If you did that, then you'd always know what the type of your result was.

Comment: Don't know C# but I would think along the lines of getting it out of PHP as JSON.  Then your question is what does C# provide for parsing JSON.  Which I imagine must be pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Servy Thank you for the suggestion. I will revise and update the question.

Comment: @Chad The WSDL was generated. But the Parameter is of type Object. We got the structure from the Documentation. Have been struggling to create a proper c# structure which can be serialized and passed to the Web Service. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question directly, the nearest possible structure in C# is a `Dictionary`, or rather, `Dictionary<string, object>`

```
$getOurRequest => array( 
  `aaaa`=> ‘1111’,
  `bbbb`=> ‘2222’,
  `ccccArray`=> array( ‘cccc3333’, ‘cccc4444‘ ),
  `ddddArray`=>array( 'dddd5555','dddd6666' )
);
```

I actually do not understand notation `$getOurRequest => array(...);`. Shouldn't it be plain = instead of => here ?

Either way, in C# analogous variable declaration would be:

```
var getOurRequest = new Dictionary<string, object>
{ 
  {"aaaa", "1111"},
  {"bbbb", "2222"},
  {"ccccArray", new string[] { "cccc3333", "cccc4444" } },
  {"ddddArray", new string[] { "dddd5555", "dddd6666" } }
);
```

However, I think that will **not solve** your problem of sending a HTTP request. For this, you will need `HttpWebRequest` object, just as Jensen answered, and all the "keys" and "values" from the hashmap/array/dictionary above will need to be provided as the query parameters.

@SOAP: If you can emit WSDL for the `web service`, then VisualStudio/C#/svcutil can generate a series of proxy classes that will simplify calling the web service very much. If you can do it, drop a note and we'll give you links to how to do that.. or just search the google on "C# call webservice"..

Out of curiosity - if you don't know C# and know PHP well, why do you ask for C# code?

Edit:
In the comments, you've said about "object parameter". In PHP or JS there is a little difference between objects and keyed arrays. In C# it's a big difference because the "dictionary" or any other hashmap will be serialized most probably as a "series of keys and values" - not as an object with fields/keys with values.. If you indeed need to pass an "object", you need to actually have a class and object instance.

```
//[DataContract] - pick one of them
//[Serializable] - they are required, but without seeing your code, it is hard to tell which one
public class MyWebServiceParameter
{
    public string aaaa {get;set;} // those must be properties, not fields
    public string bbbb {get;set;}
    public string[] ccccArray {get;set;}
    public string[] ddddArray {get;set;}
}

....
var tmp = new MyWebServiceParameter
{
     aaaa = "1111", bbbb = "2222",
     ccccArray = new string[] { "....", "...." },
     ddddArray = new string[] { "....", "...." }
};
```

Just be sure to uncomment one of the "attribtues" - datacontract/serializable. Both of them tell the C# runtime that this class is allowed to be serialized, but each of them comes from a different library or rather, era of networking approach in .Net. In general, each of them could be OK, but one will be better depending on how/what has been generated from the WSDL and what .Net and what extra libraries you are using. If you are using 'state-of-art' .Net, then pick DataContract.

Now, you say you have WSDL? So right-click on your project and choose "Add service reference" or "add web reference" and in the popup dialog enter the URL to your WSDL. The creator should be able to parse it and it will generate a series of support classes for that webservice. Lets say they got called "MyPHPService" and it defines an operation called 'TheServiceMethodName':

```
var serv = new MyPHPService();
serv.TheServiceMethodName( tmp ); // just pass the object you have created earlier. Or a dictionary, or other..
```

if your WSDL is OK and if the creator understood it right, then for a call to the SOAP service only those two lines are needed!

Comment: Thank you for the c# var declaration. I am writing code in c# client to consume a php web service. I already have generated the WSDL and am attempting to pass the object parameter needed in the above sample structure. So far it has been futile to get this dictionary to serialize. Thank you again.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some info on objects and webservices

Comment: #quetzalcoatl Thank you very much for the update. It was helpful again. I have marked the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're calling your PHP service, so my answer is based on a personal project.

I had no interest into creating a SOAP service and whatnot because C# was not the only language I was communicating with and I wanted to keep things simple. Just use an `HttpWebRequest` to call a web-server and analyze the page output.

So, I used JSON. There's a powerful library from James Newton-King called [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). It can both convert objects to and from JSON.

On the PHP side, these functions are build into the PHP interpreter: [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Is that dudes name an anagram for "JSON Tweaking Men"?

Comment: @ficuscr, sure seems to be! Or "JSON Tweeking Man" (with bad spelling)